# Use external CSS

Tags: css

I embedded the CSS in my web page and works fine. But I try to make it as an external CSS, it won't work at all. Just don't know how to fix the problem!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #cellPic{
            background-image: url("./pics/bird.png");      
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="cellPic">
            <tr>
                <td id="cell0">0</td>
                <td id="cell1">1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
//External CSS named style.css:
#cellPic{
    background-image: url("./pics/bird.png");  
}
//My web page with the external CSS (won't work)
<html> 
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="cellPic">
            <tr>
                <td id="cell0">0</td>
                <td id="cell1">1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any helps...

Comment: It seems correct regarding syntax. Are you sure the path css/style.css is correct with respect to the HTML?

Comment: try using <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>

Comment: your css folder and html file is in same folder?

Comment: check the path of css file or check the path of background-image which you are adding

Comment: Or maybe you need to change the path to the image in your external css file because it's located in the *css* folder and still has the same path to the image

Comment: Tell us where your style.css file is exactly and where your HTML file is

Comment: Tell use about the folder structure. path of your html, css and image files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code kindly add ../ in image path like below:

```
#cellPic{
background-image: url("../pics/bird.png");
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see the paths are not the same for an external css (../folder/pic.jpg) and an embedded on (./folder/pic.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

please check css path as well image url path is correct or not.

Here is 
[working example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxyuan?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Answer (score 0):

I think your css is linked but problem in background image path. it's look like bellow:

you need to change in path of **style.css:-**

```
#cellPic{
     background-image: url("./../pics/bird.png");  
}
```